# Relative paths in SBT builds with multiple nested projects

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an SBT build that looks something like this :

```scala
name := "foo"

version := "1.0"

lazy val schemaFile = settingKey[File]("File containing FIX schema for generator")

schemaFile := (resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "input.xml"

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= Def.task {
  import my.project.SourceGenerator
  lazy val filename : String = schemaFile.value.getName.toLowerCase.stripSuffix(".xml") + ".scala"
  lazy val outFile : File = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / filename
  outFile.getParentFile.mkdirs()
  Seq(SourceGenerator.generate(schemaFile.value,outFile))
}
```

`SourceGenerator.generate()` converts the input *.xml into a *.scala `File`.

This seems to work fine when run by itself. Now, this is actually a sub-directory of a larger set of projects, which have dependencies between them. So, I've tried to follow the SBT guide to create a parent *bulid.sbt* file one level up, and included this project like so:

```scala
// build.sbt in the directory directly above foo's build.sbt
lazy val foo = project

lazy val bar = project dependsOn foo
```

Now when I try to load this configuration I get an error like this:

```
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? r
C:\**\rootproj\foo\build.sbt:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.io.File
 required: T
schemaFile := (resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "input.xml"
```

What's going on here? Am I going about this the wrong way - i.e. isn't it safe to nest sbt builds inside one another, with a parent 'root' build?

p.s. on a side-note, can somebody point to the api doc for `/` operator, and `<+=`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem. When I do something similar, it works.
I have kept the `build.sbt` file in the `foo` folder, and declared the projects and dependency in another `build.sbt` in the parent folder, which happens to be the topmost project. I'm using `SBT 0.13.2`.

I have set the following:

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(foo, bar)
lazy val foo = project
lazy val bar = project.dependsOn(foo)
```

But removing the first line does make it fail like yours. I suspect you have another compilation issue, or just that I'm just not able to figure out your exact situation.

## `/` operator

`/` operator is [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.RichFile).

It is available through an implicit conversion from `File` to `RichFile` that makes the `/` method available. `file / "test"` is going to be rewritten to `new RichFile(file)./("test")` by the Scala compiler.

In actuality, you don't have to understand this: just use `/` as an operator to combine a folder (as a `File`) and segment of the path (as a `String`).

## `<+=` operator

`<+=` operator is [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.SettingKey), but I don't think this is going to help, because there is some kind of macro and implicit magic.

## Simplified operators in SBT 0.13.x

SBT version 0.12.x was mentioning this operator before in the docs, but is not anymore in version 0.13.x, or just as traces. In version 0.13.x, that you appear to be using, a number of the cryptic operators on keys are supposed to be replaced by a smaller set of more familiar operators and  the use of the `value` method.

- `:=` (assignment, `=` can not be used)
- `+=` (add one item)
- `++=` (add several items)

You might as well write your code like the following. Here we are trying to add a `Task` (more precisely a `Task[Seq[File]]`) to a `Seq[Task]` (more precisely a `Seq[Task[Seq[File]]]`), so we just want to add one task and use the `+=` operator. `taskValue` allows you to delay the evaluation of the task.

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  lazy val filename : String = schemaFile.value.getName.toLowerCase.stripSuffix(".xml") + ".scala"
  lazy val outFile : File = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / filename
  outFile.getParentFile.mkdirs()
  Seq(generate(schemaFile.value, outFile))
}.taskValue
```